# Where can I ask a question like this?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm not exactly sure where to ask this question. But since its Music related I thought you guys could help me. Its kind of a weird question.

> On Garage band there's an option called groove track. When used, instead of just quantizing it to the bpm, it quantizes it to a loop or melody of your choosing in your track. I was wondering if there is a plugin or program somewhere that instead of just quantizing the notes to a specific melody, it also changes the notes to harmonize with that melody.

If this doesn't match the questions asked here, do you guys know where I can ask this question?

Comment: I strongly recommend that before accepting any particular recommendation, you look at the respective Help Centers, and specifically the sections on what you can and can't ask about.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a request for plugin or program recommendation, you can ask the question on the [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).